# (FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "cat.png"), getting this error even when my .pnmg is in my folder and in my work space

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hX01d.png)
error code

My .png is in my folder and is in my workspace but i keep getting this error and putting r"cat.png" doesn't work same as changing \ to /.

Comment: Is the output of `os.path.abspath('cat.png')` the correct path?

Comment: `cat.png` does not exist _in the current directory_.  The current directory is not necessarily the same directory where your python script is.

Comment: the cat.png is in my folder and in my workspace I updated the image at the top

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the root directory is different from where you are running the python file. A quick solution is you can provide complete location of the cat.png file. For example

> C://users//gksso//.......//cat.png

Answer (score 0):

if you could paste your code here more help could be provided, but here is some code

```
backg = ('background.jpg')
```

As you can see i have created a variable that is assigned to the .png file you are trying to use. It should then work. Also make sure your .png file is properly put into your projects directories, like shown below. This is just an example.

[image: Example of a .png file in a projects directory.(This ide is called replit!)]

Comment: OP has already put the image alongside with the program script.  Also it is a comment more than an answer.

Comment: Hi I tried that backg = ('cat.png') it still doesn't work, my .png is in my folder just like yours as well that's why I'm still confused on why I'm getting this error

Comment: i updated the image im still confused

Comment: Are you sure you have added that folder and opened the contents soorya